# Olá pessoal. Alguém pode me informar porque o resultado da consulta abaixo está trazendo nos primeiros 4 registros o Saldo Zerado?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Alguém pode me informar porque o resultado da consulta abaixo está trazendo nos primeiros 4 registros o Saldo Zerado? Estou calculando as Entradas mais as saídas. Calcula corretamente caso hajam valores nas duas colunas, mas quando não existe valor na coluna [SAI] o resultado também fica com zero.

O que eu esperava: ENT=10 + SAI=0 => SLD=10

**Query:**

```
select t1.Z1_COD, 
     (SELECT SUM(t2.Z1_QTD) FROM SZ1010 t2 WHERE t1.Z1_COD=t2.Z1_COD AND t2.Z1_TPMOV = 'E' ) as ENT,
     (SELECT SUM(t3.Z1_QTD) FROM SZ1010 t3 WHERE t1.Z1_COD=t3.Z1_COD AND t3.Z1_TPMOV = 'S' ) as SAI, 
     (SELECT SUM(t2.Z1_QTD) FROM SZ1010 t2 WHERE t1.Z1_COD=t2.Z1_COD AND t2.Z1_TPMOV = 'E' ) + (SELECT SUM(t3.Z1_QTD) FROM SZ1010 t3 WHERE t1.Z1_COD=t3.Z1_COD AND t3.Z1_TPMOV = 'S' )  as SLD
     FROM  SZ1010 t1
```

**Resultado**
[image: Coluna ENT - SAI zerado]

Comment: E o mesmo Z1_COD aparecendo várias vezes na primeira coluna, é normal? Acho que essa query vai precisar passar por algum tipo de reestruturação.

Comment: Teste o `SUM` da seguinte forma: `SUM(ISNULL(t2.Z1_QTD, 0))`

Comment: É provavel que haja valores de `SAI` que esteja `null` no banco, e estes estão sendo inferidos como `0` em algum momento no resultado, mas na fórmula está anulando o resultado também.

Answer (score 2):

Possivelmente não existem registos nas condições indicadas, pelo que é recomendado colocar o ISNULL(coluna, 0), de forma a que se não existirem dados, então assume o valor zero.

Porém, para obteres os dados que pretendes, podes fazer uma INNER QUERY (query dentro de outra), da seguinte forma:

```
SELECT Z1_COD, ENT, SAI, ENT - SAI AS SLD
FROM
(
    select t1.Z1_COD, 
         ISNULL((SELECT SUM(t2.Z1_QTD) FROM SZ1010 t2 WHERE t1.Z1_COD=t2.Z1_COD AND t2.Z1_TPMOV = 'E' ), 0) as ENT,
         ISNULL((SELECT SUM(t3.Z1_QTD) FROM SZ1010 t3 WHERE t1.Z1_COD=t3.Z1_COD AND t3.Z1_TPMOV = 'S' ), 0) as SAI, 
         FROM  SZ1010 t1
) T
```

Answer (score 0):

Tenta fazer da seguinte forma:

```
SELECT 
    T1.Z1_COD, 
    (SELECT ISNULL(SUM(T2.Z1_QTD),0) FROM SZ1010 T2 WHERE T1.Z1_COD=T2.Z1_COD AND T2.Z1_TPMOV = 'E' ) AS ENT,
    (SELECT ISNULL(SUM(T3.Z1_QTD),0) FROM SZ1010 T3 WHERE T1.Z1_COD=T3.Z1_COD AND T3.Z1_TPMOV = 'S' ) AS SAI, 
    (SELECT ISNULL(SUM(T2.Z1_QTD),0) FROM SZ1010 T2 WHERE T1.Z1_COD=T2.Z1_COD AND T2.Z1_TPMOV = 'E' ) + (SELECT ISNULL(SUM(T3.Z1_QTD),0) FROM SZ1010 T3 WHERE T1.Z1_COD=T3.Z1_COD AND T3.Z1_TPMOV = 'S' )  AS SLD
FROM  
    SZ1010 T1
```

Comment: É sempre interessante explicar o porquê da alteração na resposta. Ensine a pescar e não dê o peixe.